# Xamarin.Android app doesn't request "WriteExternalStorage" (but code works fine with "ReadExternalStorage")

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, android-permissions

I already have some experiences with C#, but I'm new to Android-Development and wanted to start with a simple project app, that can create a new directory with a file on the external storage ("/storage/emulated/0/" [Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageDirectory.AbsolutePath]) and read it.

In the documentation I read that in the newer SDKs it's not enough to mention the permissions (in this case "ANDROID.PERMISSION.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE") in the AndroidManifest.xml. So I added a method to request them at runtime.

My problem is that the emulator [Android 8.1 API 27] (and my phone with USB debugging [Android 8.0]) doesn't open the permission dialogue, if I request "Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage".
If I use my code to request "Manifest.Permission.ReadExternalStorage" the dialogue appears, you can accept and decline and the action visible in the settings.

First, I tried to write my own code to the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/xamarin/android/platform/files/external-storage), which doesn't open the dialogue. I tried to let a NuGet-Package (Karamunting.Android.PermissionManager) manage the request, same problem: It just asked for the read permission, not write. Now I'm using code that I copied from a GitHub project (https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/LocalFiles), but still the same problem.

This is the method that should request the permission

```cs
const int RC_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION = 1000;
static readonly string[] PERMISSIONS_TO_REQUEST = { Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage };

bool RequestExternalStoragePermissionIfNecessary(int requestCode)
        {
            if (Android.OS.Environment.MediaMounted.Equals(Android.OS.Environment.ExternalStorageState))
            {
                if (CheckSelfPermission(Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage) == Permission.Granted)
                {
                    Log.Debug(TAG, "Neccessary permissions granted");
                    return false;
                }

                Log.Debug(TAG, "Permissions denied --> requesting");
                if (ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage))
                {
                    Snackbar.Make(FindViewById(Android.Resource.Id.Content),
                                  Resource.String.write_external_permissions_rationale,
                                  Snackbar.LengthIndefinite)
                            .SetAction(Resource.String.ok, delegate { RequestPermissions(PERMISSIONS_TO_REQUEST, requestCode); });
                }
                else
                {
                    RequestPermissions(PERMISSIONS_TO_REQUEST, requestCode);
                }

                return true;
            }

            Log.Warn(TAG, "External storage is not mounted; cannot request permission");
            return true;
        }
```

It is called on a button click , but I also tried to use it in the OnCreate() method

```cs
bool useIntern = RequestExternalStoragePermissionIfNecessary(RC_WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION);
```

I've also mentioned the permissions in the AndroidManifest

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="23" android:targetSdkVersion="27" />
<uses-permission android:name="ANDROID.PERMISSION.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I expect that the application will check on startup/ button click if the permission is granted (It does check for permission and writes in the console "Permissions denied --> requesting").

But after that the app should show the dialogue "Allow App to […] on your device? - Deny - Allow". This doesn't happen if I request the write permission, but happens if I request read.

Thanks for any kind of help in Advance

Phil

Comment: you could debug `if (ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage))` this line to see if it return true or false,if true,it will show dilaog,if false,it won't show.However, in actual development, it should be noted that many phones have made changes to the native system,some phones `ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationale` will always return false

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT your right, `ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage))` returns false, but shouldn't the the applications ask for permission with executing `RequestPermissions(PERMISSIONS_TO_REQUEST, requestCode);` in the else-block then? Or is there a better way to get the permission?

Comment: I seem to have misunderstood your meaning.Do you now call `RequestPermissions()` method without the dialog box?if yes,have you add  `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` into your `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT I'm not 100% sure if I used `RequestPermissions()` correct, but it's called if `ShouldShowRequestPermissionRationale` returns false. 
`static readonly string[] PERMISSIONS_TO_REQUEST = { Manifest.Permission.WriteExternalStorage };` `RequestPermissions(PERMISSIONS_TO_REQUEST, 1000);` I've also added the use-permission in the AndroidManifest and it appeared as checked element in the listbox of the Visual Studop property tab.

Comment: your code works on my side,What is your device?

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT I tried it with my Samsung S7 edge (Android 8.0) and the emulator with default settings (API 27). I will try the code with a clean project later. Maybe there is something wrong with the project files...

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT Thank you very much for your help. Now everything works fine with a new project and a few changes in the confihuration.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the problem was not the code, but the configuration.
In the AndroidManifest.xml I changed the minSdk from 23  to 21 and the capitalization of the permission:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.companyname.testapp" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="21" android:targetSdkVersion="27" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name" android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" android:supportsRtl="true" android:theme="@style/AppTheme"></application>
</manifest>
```

Thanks for your help @LeoZhu-MSFT